# Apple Like Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I need a slider like this one

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sparrow/id417250177?mt=12 (on Screenshots)

http://storymatters.com/showcase/there-is-an-app-for-that#slideshowWrap

Ideas?

Comment: Without JavaScript, Apple's degrades terribly when compared to storymatters.com, it'd be better to emulate storymatters.

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking for code here. But I doubt anybody will just say here is the solution. I think you should start writing code and put it up.

Comment: The storymatters one breaks when you try to drag the slider (you get the "you are trying to drag an image" effect).  I've never once seen a good scrollbar replacement - there is always something broken or missing.  Suggestion:  use an actual browser scrollbar instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! I better start coding :)

Answer (score 0):

That's just a custom scroll bar that works on webkit browsers:  http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/  Here's an example

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

IE has a way to style scrollbars too, not as customizable though...

```
body { 
  scrollbar-arrow-color:#ffffff; 
  scrollbar-base-color: #ffffff; 
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color:#ffffff; 
  scrollbar-track-color:#ffffff;
  scrollbar-face-color:#ffffff; 
  scrollbar-shadow-color:#ffffff; 
  scrollbar-highlight-color:#ffffff; 
  scrollbar-3d-light-color:#ffffff; 
}
```

So, if you want this to work across browsers, you're out of luck. The only way to do it is to write your own custom html for a scroll bar with the divs set to overflow: hidden

Comment: Apple is using JavaScript and images, storymatters is using the webkit version, it appers